# Node.js C++ Addon - Setting a certain index of an array

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, fibonacci, node.js-addon

I'm trying to create a Node.js C++ Addon that generates the Fibonacci sequence to compare its speed with a normal Node.js module, but I'm having trouble setting a certain index of an array. I've got this so far:

```
#include <node.h>

namespace demo {

using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
using v8::Isolate;
using v8::Local;
using v8::Object;
using v8::Value;
using v8::Number;
using v8::Array;

void Method(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();

    int next, first = 0, second = 0, c = 0, n = args[0]->NumberValue();
    Local<Array> arr = Array::New(isolate, n);

    for (; c < n; c++) {
        if ( c <= 1 ) next = c;
        else {
            next = first + second;
            first = second;
            second = next;
        }
        // How to set arr[c]?????
    }

    args.GetReturnValue().Set(arr);
}

void init(Local<Object> exports) {
    NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "fib", Method);
}

NODE_MODULE(addon, init)

}
```

On line 26, how should I set `arr[c]`? `v8:Array` doesn't provide a subscript operator.

Comment: `Local<Number> arr[] = new Local<Number>[n];` That is not how you initialize arrays. Did you mean `Local<Number> arr[n];`?

Comment: @freakish Updated question.

Comment: Oh, `n` is a variable, fair enough. Then `Local<Number> *arr = new Local<Number>[n];` is what you are looking for. Remember to `delete` the array after you are done with it.

Comment: @freakish Ouch... `/Users/Bennett/.node-gyp/6.9.2/include/node/v8.h:7858:3: error: assigning to 'v8::Local<v8::Number> **volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Primitive *'
  TYPE_CHECK(S*, Primitive);`. Already tried that a while ago :(

Comment: I assume this is line `arr[c] = Number::New(isolate, next);`. The code is messed up, you are trying to assign to `arr` something of a different type. I don't know nodejs api, can't help you beyond that.

Comment: *Why is this happening?* -- This is proving that you can't write C++ code like this unless you know the language.  The first error is because C++ doesn't allow arrays to be declared using a variable to denote the number of entries.

Comment: You are not declaring or using `arr` properly. The `Set` method is expecting a handle to a single value, not a pointer to an array of values. What did you base your solution on?

Comment: @E_net4 I was looking over [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/addons.html#addons_function_arguments). How do I pass a JavaScript array back to the Node.js program? Is the type `v8::Array`?

Comment: @Bennett Yes, you should use that instead.

Comment: @E_net4 How should I convert the C++ array to `v8::Array`?

Comment: Consider rephrasing your own question instead of asking new ones in the comments.

Comment: @E_net4 Gotcha, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how should I set arr[c]? v8:Array doesn't provide a subscript operator.

It doesn't, but `v8::Array` already inherits the function member `Set` from [`v8::Object`](http://bespin.cz/~ondras/html/classv8_1_1Object.html), with an overload that takes an integer (`uint32_t`) for the key. Use it to populate each element of the array:

```
void Method(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();

    int next, first = 0, second = 0, c = 0, n = args[0]->NumberValue();
    Local<Array> arr = Array::New(isolate, n);

    int i = 0;
    for (; c < n; c++) {
        if ( c <= 1 ) next = c;
        else {
            next = first + second;
            first = second;
            second = next;
        }
        arr->Set(i++, Number::New(isolate, next));
    }

    args.GetReturnValue().Set(arr);
}
```

Comment: Oh! I was just looking [here](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-6.9/d3/d32/classv8_1_1_array.html), and didn't notice that `v8::Array` inherited the `Set` function. Thanks, makes more sense now.

Comment: Also, I think you meant `arr->Set` instead of `arr.Set`.

Comment: Thanks, that is fixed. In another note, you may indeed picture JavaScript arrays as special objects.

Comment: I just noticed that arrays are just objects with numbers as they keys and some other instance methods. *mind explodes*

Comment: In addition, nothing prevents you from adding fields with a non-numeric key, just like in JavaScript: `var a = [1,2,3]; a.five = 'six';`

Comment: Yup. That's also why you don't use `for (x in y)` loops as it will loop through those keys like `five`. For example, `for (b in a) { console.log(b); }` will log `1`, `2`, `3`, and `five`.